# ¿Cómo agregar una función de autocomplete en inputs dinámicos?

Tags: javascript, php, html, autocomplete

Tengo un input con id ailments con una función de autocomplete, cuando el usuario escribe una palabra o letra, saldrán datos de la BD, lo hace bien con este primer input, pero ahora lo que estoy haciendo es con ayuda de un botón, agregar otros input con el mismo id, el mismo name, también todo bien. Pero al momento de escribir una palabra o letra en los demás inputs agregados con el botón, no aparece nada, no esta realizando alguna acción, solamente en el primero. No comprendo bien por que no esta funcionando.
Dejo mi código:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="ailments[]" id="ailments" class="form-control bg-light border border-success" placeholder="Padecimiento" autocomplete="off" >
```

js:

```
<script>
        $(function () {
            $("#ailments").autocomplete({
                source: 'insertconsult/search_ailments.php'
            });
        });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // agregar registro
        $("#addRow").click(function () {
            var html = '';
            html += '<div id="inputFormRow">';
            html += '<div class="input-group mb-3">';
            html += '<input type="text" name="ailments[]" id="ailments" class="form-control bg-light border border-success" placeholder="Padecimiento" autocomplete="off" >';
            html += '<div class="input-group-append">';
            html += '<button id="removeRow" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Borrar</button>';
            html += '</div>';
            html += '</div>';

            $('#newRow').append(html);
        });

        // borrar registro
        $(document).on('click', '#removeRow', function () {
            $(this).closest('#inputFormRow').remove();
        });
    </script>
```

Archivo search_ailments:

```
<?php

$conexion = new Connection();
$pdo = $conexion->getConexion();
$statement = $pdo->prepare("select * from padecimientos where nombre_pade like :keyword");
$statement->bindValue('keyword', '%'.$_GET['term'].'%');
$statement->execute();
$result = array();
while($product = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
    array_push($result, $product->nombre_pade);
}
echo json_encode($result);

?>
```

Comment: Empieza corrigiendo los errores básicos, como tener ids duplicados. Un id debe ser único, imagínate lo que podría pasar en cualquier país si sus ciudadanos tuviesen ID repetidos, crees que funcionaría bien? Pues lo mismo en tu html, si tienes dos campos con el mismo id, cuando intenta enlazar el autocompletar lo hace al primer id que encuentra (porque debería haber solo uno!).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Omitiendo como solucionar el problema de los id, expresado por @Benito-B en los comentarios, lo podrias solucionar de la siguiente forma (eso no quiere decir que no esté mal, simplemente que no los vamos a requerir con esta solución):

- Agrega una clase, por ejemplo, **ailments** al input inicial, y elimina el id, de tal forma que quede así:

```
<input type="text" name="ailments[]" class="ailments form-control bg-light border border-success" placeholder="Padecimiento" autocomplete="off" >
```

- Haz lo mismo en la linea donde aparece el input, al crear el nuevo input:

```
html += '<input type="text" name="ailments[]" class="ailments form-control bg-light border border-success" placeholder="Padecimiento" autocomplete="off" >';
```

- Sustituye toda esta llamada al autocomplete:

```
$(function () {
  $("#ailments").autocomplete({
    source: 'insertconsult/search_ailments.php'
  });
});
```

por esto otro (**RE-ACTUALIZACIÓN!**):

```
$('body').on("focusin", '.ailments', function (event) {
    $(event.target).autocomplete({
      source: 'insertconsult/search_ailments.php'
    });
  });
```

donde lo que hacemos es vincular el evento **focus in** (es decir, cuando un elemento coge el foco) detectado en cualquier elemento del body, y mediante delegación de eventos, detectamos si son elementos de la clase **ailments**, y si lo son ejecutamos la función donde **event.target** representa el elemento actual que ha recibido el foco y sobre el cual realizamos el autocomplete.

Esta delegación de eventos nos asegura que cada vez que un nuevo elemento creado dinámicamente recibe un evento, en este caso de foco, el código anterior lo interpretará y analizará, y si ese nuevo elemento tiene la clase esperada entonces ejecutará la función.

Es la forma más usual de conseguir que los elementos dinámicos respondan a eventos indirectamente, pues hay que tener en cuenta que **cualquier evento es pasado desde su elemento origen hasta su ancestro más superior, pasando antes por todos y cada uno de los elementos que lo contengan previamente**, y eso ocurre siempre, por lo tanto tampoco estamos sobrecargando nada, sino aprovechándonos de ello, que ya ocurre sin que nos demos cuenta.

Dejo este snippet con todo (que aquí no funciona completamente porque no puede ejecutar el PHP):

```js
$('body').on("focusin", '.ailments', function(event) {
  $(event.target).autocomplete({
    source: 'insertconsult/search_ailments.php'
  });
});

// agregar registro
$("#addRow").click(function() {
  var html = '';
  html += '<div id="inputFormRow">';
  html += '<div class="input-group mb-3">';
  html += '<input type="text" name="ailments[]" class="ailments form-control bg-light border border-success" placeholder="Padecimiento" autocomplete="off" >';
  html += '<div class="input-group-append">';
  html += '<button id="removeRow" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Borrar</button>';
  html += '</div>';
  html += '</div>';

  $('#newRow').append(html);
});

// borrar registro
$(document).on('click', '#removeRow', function() {
  $(this).closest('#inputFormRow').remove();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="ailments[]" class="ailments form-control bg-light border border-success" placeholder="Padecimiento" autocomplete="off">
<div id="newRow"></div>
<button id="addRow">Agregar</button>
```

Comment: Excelente explicación, muy atendible. Muchísimas gracias por tu respuesta, ahora entiendo mejor en como realizar esto. Gracias!

Comment: Me alegro que te haya funcionado... lo único que luego he pensado es en mi frase `tampoco estamos sobrecargando nada`, lo cual es cierto a nivel de control de eventos, pero si tenemos en cuenta que estamos ejecutando el script php cada vez que un input coge el foco, quizás podria causar problemas de sobrecarga en el servidor (que no en el cliente) al lanzar demasiadas peticiones php a tu script si al usuario le da por hacer click continuamente entre los inputs cambiando el foco y provocando el evento focus in.

Comment: Eso se podría solucionar modificando el autocomplete para que lo coja de una variable, la cual se debería rellenar con una petición ajax sólo la primera vez que suceda ese evento, y una vez rellenada no volver a ejecutar el ajax.  Si te interesa arreglar eso mejor que lo pongas en una nueva pregunta para no liarla más aquí, gracias.

Comment: Gracias por tu actualización, me ayudaste en mucho, ahora entiendo cual fue el problema y la solución. Muchas gracias @masterguru

Comment: Je, ayer estaba bastante espeso y no vi lo evidente. He vuelto a actualizar la respuesta.  El problema que tenia antes era que intentaba usar `$('.ailments')` como si fuera un **selector**, cuando con esa sintaxis representa objetos jquery.  El selector es sin la `$()`, es decir, solo `'.ailments'`. Revisa mi respuesta donde pongo lo de `$('body').on("focusin", '.ailments', function(event) {` y verás que ahora sí funciona sin tener que usar el condicional con el `.hasClass` de mi anterior actualización.