# ¿Cómo puedo guardar un input dinámico en mi Base de datos?

Tags: html, codeigniter, input, bootstrap-file-input

Hola grupo espero me puedan ayudar quiero hacer un input dinámico agrego ejemplo
[ejemplo de input](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/535135/c%C3%B3mo-agregar-una-funci%C3%B3n-de-autocomplete-en-inputs-din%C3%A1micos)
[ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/90489/guardar-datos-de-formulario-dinamico)

Funciona el script ya que si agrega y borra los input pero no se como guardarlos dejo mis datos
de cada parte de mi código para ver  si me pueden ayudar

**CONTROLADOR**

esta parte la utilizo para guardar los datos pero me sale un error

> **Unknown column 'Array' in 'field list'**

También me sale este otro error por el array

> **Severity: Notice**
>
> **Message: Array to string conversion**
>
> **Filename: database/DB_driver.php**
>
> **Line Number: 1471**
>
> **Backtrace:**
>
> **File: C:\xampp\htdocs\test3\application\models\Automobiles_model.php**
> **Line: 9 Function: insert**
>
> **File: C:\xampp\htdocs\test3\application\controllers\automobile\Add.php**
> **Line: 80 Function: save**
>
> **File: C:\xampp\htdocs\test3\index.php Line: 315**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Add extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        if($this->session->userdata('is_logged')==true)//verifica si esta logeado
        {

        $this->load->model("Automobiles_model");
        $categorias = $this->Automobiles_model->getUsers();
        $datos['categorias'] = $categorias;
  
        $this->load->view('base_site/head');
        $this->load->view('side/ver');
        $this->load->view('automobile/add',$datos);
        $this->load->view('base_site/footer');
        $this->load->view('base_site/scripts');
    }else
    {
        redirect(base_url());

    }

    }
    public function index()
    {

    }

    public function save(){

    $Serie = $this->input->post("Serie");
        
            $data = array(
                
                "Serie"=>$Serie,
                

            );
            
            $this->Automobiles_model->save($data);
            $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Se guardo los datos correctamente');
            redirect(base_url()."automoviles");
        
    }
}
```

**vista**

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>nuevo-automoviles/save"
         class="mt-4" method="POST">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12">
<div id="inputFormRow">
<div class="input-group mb-3">
<input type="text" name="Serie[]" class="form-control m-input"
 placeholder="Ingrese titulo" autocomplete="off">
<div class="input-group-append"> 
<button id="removeRow" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Borrar</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div id="newRow"></div>
<button id="addRow" type="button" class="btn btn-info">Agregar</button>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
</div>
</form>
```

**script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// agregar registro
$("#addRow").click(function () { 
var html = '';
html += '<div id="inputFormRow">';
html += '<div class="input-group mb-3">';
html += '<input type="text" name="Serie[]" class="form-control m-input" placeholder="Ingrese titulo" autocomplete="off">';
html += '<div class="input-group-append">';
html += '<button id="removeRow" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Borrar</button>';
html += '</div>';
html += '</div>';

$('#newRow').append(html);
});

// borrar registro
$(document).on('click', '#removeRow', function () {
$(this).closest('#inputFormRow').remove();
});
</script>
```

**base de datos**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Está preparada tu tabla para guardar por ejemplo, mas de 8 campos (inputs) creados por el usuario?

Comment: mi tabla de datos pongo una imagen esta en phpmyadmin

Comment: Creo que este video podría ayudarte: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wuE6-gyW4bA&ab_channel=Tech.Rudranshi

Comment: ¿Aún estás esperando ayuda o ya pudiste resolverlo?

Comment: aun espero ayudo

Comment: como es eso de que tu tabla esta en phpmyadmin... las base de datos se hacen el mysql y phpmyadmin es un gestor ...

Comment: Hola, Bienvenid@ al Sitio, veo que eres nuev@ te recomendaria hacer el [tour] para que conoscas mejor el sitio, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].